# django auth_views.login and redirects

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-templates

I could not understand why after logging in from address:

```
http://localhost/en/accounts/login/?next=/en/test/
```

I get refirected to

```
http://localhost/accounts/profile/
```

So i ran search in django files and found that this address is the default LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL for django.

What i did not understand is why it gets redirected to there. I guessed, that my login form's post address should be :

```
/accounts/login/?next=/en/test/
```

instead of

```
/accounts/login/
```

I wrote it into template and it worked. But since the redirect url changes dynamically, how can i make this login post forms address change dynamically too? is there a templatetag for that or something?

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acutally, i think i figured it out... I should not change login forms post address, but just post the form to the same address where i am.

edit:It worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

In settings.py you may set the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL